# Logo for Natural Language Processing

Tags: graphics

Searching **Natural Language Processing** in Google Image search gives many images of this type:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that there are only horizontal and vertical texts with random formatting. What is a generic way to get this?

Comment: http://www.wordle.net/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/917/wordle-like-word-clouds http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/wordle-like-word-clouds-can-it-be-done-without-using-an-image?lq=1

Comment: Work in progress: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180510