# Word Cloud - Searchable (no images) for research keywords

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to create a word cloud with LaTex for my research keywords. I would like to make it searchable (thus not an image) and to make sure that LaTex does not divide my research keywords (which might be composed by two or more terms, with no hyphens).

The best approach that I could find on the net is the following:

[Wordle-like word clouds - can it be done without using an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/wordle-like-word-clouds-can-it-be-done-without-using-an-image)

but I still have two problems with this code (I am not an expert in programming...).

1) The code does not allow me to have a two or more terms keywords. Imagine my two keywords are (i) differential equations, and (ii) partial differential equations; I would like LaTex to consider the keyword differential equations as a single word when developing the word cloud. I tried with \mbox and \tabfill but this does not work (LaTex even show mbox and tabfill in the cloud!)

2) I do not understand how to control the size of the box in which the word cloud is shown. Imagine I want to have a box with width of 10cm and height of 5cm. How can I do so?

Thanks for your help.