# buzzword overview solutions (word cloud)

Tags: packages, tikz-styles, mindmaps

Is there anything out there I easily can create a **buzzword overview** with? A Package or templates?

*(buzzword overview := bunch of words, horizontally and vertically squeezed together in different color and sizes, similar to a mindmap)*

I could use tikz of course and try to place, rotate and color every word by itself. But usually there is someone out there who had the same idea, time to do it and especialy more skills than I could offer and created something to safe the effort.
There seems to be a mindmap option in tikz but I am looking for a rather un-hierarchical solution where the words dont rely on each other.
Any hint, even for how to do this by myself will be much appreciated.

EDIT: As there are copyrights, the suggested example of what I want is provided behind this [link](https://www.matillion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/business-intelligence-basics-buzzwords.png).
I have not tried anything so far, since the only thing I can think of to do, is what I am trying to avoid: Drawing something like behind the link from scratch with TiKz.

Comment: I guess you will have much better chances of getting a quick answer if you (a) provide a sketch of how that should look like and (b) show us what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this will straighten my request.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/917/wordle-like-word-clouds

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/wordle-like-word-clouds-can-it-be-done-without-using-an-image?noredirect=1&lq=1