# Word collage style in (Xe)LaTeX

Tags: xetex, diagrams

I'm thinking about making something like this in (Xe)LaTeX:

[image]

Would it be feasible to make?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible.  If you want to know *how*, you should rephrase your question and include a MWE.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/917/wordle-like-word-clouds

Comment: this answer might be even more appropriate: [Showcase TeX Typography for TUG's Calendar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146178/579)