# Word Collage-Cloud with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I recently found this picture [image: picture]

And I wanted to do something like that **with tikz**.
Can someone do to me a MWE?

Comment: Use http://www.wordle.net and include the image. See also [Wordle-like word clouds](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/917)

Comment: No I need with tikz...

Comment: Any reason for insisting on TikZ? And in that case, do you want an automatically generated cloud based on a text, or do you just want to manually position individual words? By the way, see also [Showcase TeX Typography for TUG's Calendar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146178) (though this uses R to generate the TikZ code).

Comment: Yes, I want to manually position individual words. Just need a minimal example..

Comment: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\Huge\bfseries}]
\node (a) at (0,0) {Word};
\node [blue,anchor=north,rotate=90] (b) at (a.east) {Awesome};
\node [red,scale=2] at (-0.5,1) {Cool};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: I would also recommend you to look at some learning material if you want to use TikZ, see [Materials for learning TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779)